# Any applicable window function in DolphinDB to contain the first and last few lines in a window?

Tags: dolphindb

For a column of data, if the current value is the lowest value of the first five values and also the lowest of the last five values, then it returns 1, otherwise 0. How can I obtain the result using DolphinDB functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `window` and `iif` for conditional assignment in a window on DolphinDB version 1.30.16/2.00.4 or later. For example:

```
t=table(rand(1..100, 20) as id, rand(`a`b`c`, 20) as v)
select *, iif(id==window(min, id, -4:4), 1, 0) as mid from t
```